# SearchView which overlaps ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

Instead of using an **ActionLayout** to replace the ActionBar when pressed a **MenuItem**. I want that ActionLayout to overlap on the ActionBar.

Since most of the applications use this behavior I thought its the standard **SearchView** widget.

And since my application is for API 10 and more, i couldn't use **SearchView**, hence used latest **ActionBarSherlock** library(4.2.0), where Jake added SearchView.

The problem is, even here its like replacing the initial menu items with the **ActionViewClass**.

The reason i want the **ActionLayout** to overlap but not replace the **ActionBar** is, I need to have 3 MenuItems in the ActionBar and if i keep all of them as

```
android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

they are even visible when **ActionLayout** is shown, which gives little width for the **ActionLayout**

if i am using

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

the last icon is missing. Only 2 icons are visible.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having physical menu button (e.g. Nexus S) in your device then the dot line will not show. When you press the Menu button it’ll show up.

You may use something as this Use `android:showAsAction="never"` to force an action item into the overflow.